# How to determine color in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors, hsv

I would like to map HSV values to color names in MATLAB. I have converted RGB to HSV and thresholded the values using a series of if statements in order to determine the color . However I would instead like to map the values to defined color names. Is this possible in MATLAB?

Comment: `hsv2rgb` will give you the rgb colour values.

Comment: Hello, welcome. Note that the processing tag (removed) is for processing.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working with an mxnx3 (i.e. 2D with 3 channels) RGB image `im`, then typically the red channel is `im(:,:,1)`, green is `im(:,:,2)`, and blue is `im(:,:,3)`. So if you want the RGB values at some point (x, y), then you can get the vector by `im(x,y,:)`.

If you just want to convert HSV values to RGB, then you can use the function [`hsv2rgb`.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hsv2rgb.html?refresh=true)

Comment: Thanks, but i more meant like I want to know qualitatively what color it is from the array, not just the RGB value.

Comment: Oh, like "This color is baby blue"? That's really a pretty open-ended question (one man's baby blue is another's sky blue, after all). You need to define a mapping from a color space to the set of color names you're interested in in order to do that. For example, there are the [CSS color names.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colornames.asp) One way to do this would be to define a lookup table where the keys are hex values (or RGB triplets or something else unique) and the values are the color names. But you'll have to pick the mapping yourself.

Comment: Exactly. I was trying to do something aligning with the Hue Color wheel whereby different color ranges are given by different angles. But i'm not sure on how to begin implementing that in matlab.

Comment: Matlab has a [containers.Map](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html) class that might be useful, though I've never used it myself so I can't vouch for it. In general, read up on hash tables to understand how this sort of problem is usually tackled.